# Flask, MongoEngine, Wtforms - rendering a passwordfield and datetime field correctly

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, wtforms

So I'm using MongoEngine, Flask, and WTForms to put together a simple webapp, and I've got a user model that looks like this:

```
class User(db.document):
    username = db.StringField(max_length=64)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=64)
    date_joined = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Now when I use MongoEngine's model_form() (from flask.ext.mongoengine.wtf) to create a form and then render it in a template, the DateTimeField and the StringField() on the password attribute both appear to be rendered as simple text input fields.

How do I get them to render as a calendar widget (like Django does) and a password field that actually obscures the password without having to custom write my own form?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but it's also high up on Google when looking for this problem.

I've dug into the flask-MongoEngine lib (specifically [here](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/1fb7ddb0df829efae9f2f3f9518c4f138c2f6d6e/flask_mongoengine/wtf/orm.py)) and found a way to do this. There's an option to pass in "field_args" a dictionary that helps modify how the fields are generated from your model.

I was having the exact same problem, but using model_form like this works:

```
form_cls = model_form(User, only=['username', 'password'], field_args={'password': {'password':True}})
```

If you dig in to the file in that link, there's a few other field that can also be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and the only way I found to solve this issue was using wtforms:

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine.wtf import model_form
from wtforms import PasswordField

class User(db.document):
    username = db.StringField(max_length=64)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=64)
    date_joined = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

user = model_form(User)
user.password = PasswordField('Password')
```

You may also want to add *[DataRequired](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/wtforms/#the-forms)* validator to your password field.